# openvpn multiple instances route issue?

Tags: linux, openvpn

I am tring to connect to form same PC to openvpn server with openvpn tow instance. I have a server with multiple IP and running tow openvpn server instances on the same Server. Trying to connect to those instances from one PC at the same time.

I can connect to them separately however when i try to connect to them together the first instance connect fine. but the second instance i get this error:

```
Thu Dec 22 05:27:04 2011 /usr/sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Thu Dec 22 05:27:04 2011 /usr/sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.10.0.5 peer 10.10.0.6
Thu Dec 22 05:27:04 2011 /usr/sbin/ip route add 184.75.xxx.xxx/32 via 10.0.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Thu Dec 22 05:27:04 2011 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Thu Dec 22 05:27:04 2011 /usr/sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.0.6
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Thu Dec 22 05:27:04 2011 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Thu Dec 22 05:27:04 2011 /usr/sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.0.6
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Thu Dec 22 05:27:04 2011 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

**Server A config**

```
port 1190
proto udp
dev tun1
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/serverA.crt
key /etc/openvpn/serverA.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh1024.pem

server 10.3.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist 10.3.0.0-ipp.txt

--mode server
--tls-server
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd.d
route 10.3.0.0 255.255.255.252

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status 10.3.0.0-openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

**Server B config**

```
port 1191
proto udp
dev tun0
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/serverB.crt
key /etc/openvpn/serverB.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh1024.pem
server 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist 10.10.0.0-ipp.txt
--mode server
--tls-server
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd.d
route 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.252

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status 10.10.0.0-openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

**Client A config**

```
client
dev tun1
proto udp
remote 184.75.xxx.xxx 1190
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client1.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client1.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
--script-security 2
```

**Client B config**

```
client
dev tun0
proto udp
remote 184.75.xxx.xxx 1191
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client2.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client2.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
--script-security 2
```

**Any help would be much appreciated.**

Comment: Can you please explain why you want multiple connections from the same client to the same server?  Are you trying to do some kind of fault tolerance for the connection, or what?

Comment: @Zoredache: I have another server on different location and i Would like to use the IPs on the vpn Server on that server

Answer (score 2):

You are basically trying to set two default gateway.  Even if you could add both routes, only one of them would work correctly.

You probably should remove the `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` from the server, and simply set up a route on the client side for which ever VPN should be the default.